# Changing urls in ruby on rails depending on different conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I'm new to ruby on rails....I wanted to know if there is a way to change the URL displayed depending on the client's response.  I mean... here's an example:
I'm making a project showing listings in various places...

Now in general I have a home page, a search page, and a detail page for listings. So, respective URLs are `officespace/home`, `officespace/search?conditions`, `officespace/detailpage?id=(controller-officespace)[&Conditions eg.---price,size,place,type...]`

So, every time the client makes a request for search, the same URL is shown, of course with the given conditions.

Now I want that if the client asks for only the place and mentions nothing about size, price, etc., the url should be `/listing/location_name`.

If he mentions other conditions, then it'll be `listing/(office_type)/size(x sq feet)_office_for_rent_in_locationname)`

B.t.w. (I already have a controller named `listings` and its purpose is something else.)

And so on ........... Actually, I want to change URLs for a number of things. Anyway, please help me. And please don't refer me to the manuals. I've already read them and they didn't give any direct help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting routing challenge.  Essentially, your goal is to create a special expression that will match the kinds of URL's you want to display in the user's browser. These expressions will be used in `match` formulas in `config/routes.rb`.  Then, you'll need to make sure the form actions and links on relevant search pages link to those specialized URL's and NOT the default pages. Here's an example to get started:

### routes.rb

```
match "/listing/:officeType/size/:squarefeet/office_for/:saleOrRent/in/:locationName" => "searches#index"
match "/listing/*locationName" => "searches#index"
resources :searches
```

Since you explicitly mentioned that your `listings` controller is for something else, I just named our new controller `searches`.  Inside the code for the `index` method for this controller, you have to decide how you want to collect the relevant data to pass along to your view. Everything marked with a `:` in the `match` expressions above will be passed to the controller in the `params` hash as if it were an HTTP `GET` query string parameter. Thus we can do the following:

### searches_controller.rb

```
def index
  if params[:squarefeet] && params[:officeType] && params[:locationName]
   @listings = Listing.where("squarefeet >= ?", params[:squarefeet].to_i).
               where(:officeType => params[:officeType],
                     :locationName => params[:locationName])
  elsif params[:locationName]
     @listings = Listing.where(:locationName => params[:locationName])
  else
     @listings = Listing.all
  end
end
```

And to send the user to one of those links:

### views/searches/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Click here for a great office!", "/listing/corporate/size/3200/office_for/rent/in/Dallas" %>
```

The above example would only work if your `Listing` model is set up exactly the same way as my arbitrary guess, but hopefully you can work from there to figure out what your code needs to look like. Note that I wasn't able to get the underscores in there. The routes only match segments separated by slashes as far as I can tell. Keep working on it and you may find a way past that.